# Why is the pricing of my GCP instance going down every week and comes back up at the beginning of each month?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, cloud

I'm running on Google Cloud. I was looking at the costs and I noticed something weird - every week the daily cost of running machines is going down, and then on the 1st day of the month, it goes back up.

It's "jumping" between $1/day up to $2.5/day, so it's very significant.

This is a screenshot of the cost breakdown of running one machine with 2 vCPUs, 7.5 GB RAM in europe-west.

[image]

Why is it going up and down? Is there any way to keep it at $1/day?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The prices don't change, but an increasing discount is applied when your instances run longer.

Google Compute offers a **sustained use discount** for running specific Compute Engine resources a significant portion of the billing month. The discounts come in a couple of tiers and start to apply after running first 25% of a month, then increase after running 50% and 75% of the month. See  https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/sustained-use-discounts

[image: graph illustrated]

An alternative to the automatically applied sustained use discount is the **committed use discount**, where signing up for one or three years is awarded with a discount:  https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/signing-up-committed-use-discounts